# Give a short name / nick name to a printer in iOS?

Tags: ios, printing

In iOS is it possible to give a short name / nick name to a printer ? I have several printers of the same spec distributed through out a building, that all show up as Epson-7620.

I know there is a feature where you can "identify" a printer, which will make it beep. But this is slow if you have to go through 5 printers to find the one you want.

Im currently running iOS 12.x on an iPhone 8.

Comment: Do you have an option to change the name *on* the printer directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Get the respective printer's IP address. Printer touchscreen menu:
   Settings > General Settings > Network Settings > Network Status > Wired LAN/Wi-Fi Status
2. Enter the IP address of the printer into a web browser (override security warning if needed).
   The web-based printer config UI appears.
   Click the ‘Basic Settings’ link (lower left, see screenshot below).

   [image: EPSON Web UI]
3. In the Basic Settings UI, click ‘AirPrint Setup’.

   [image: EPSON Basic Settings]
4. In the AirPrint Setup screen, change the Bonjour Service Name to your liking. You can also set location information.

   [image: EPSON AirPrint Setup]
5. Confirm changes by clicking the ‘OK’ button.

The info entered will appear in the AirPrint printer selection on iOS, even with location info if set.

[image: iOS AirPrint printer selection]

Repeat with every respective printer.

Comment: Note that your IT department might not like or approve of you doing this assuming it's not already locked down with a password. I've seen people do things like this and get fired for "hacking." So ask first, heck show them this post and ask them if it is OK that either you or they do it.